# Decompose CDF into discrete and absolutely continuous parts

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have found the CDF of a particular random variable to be
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}
                            0 & \text{ for } x < 0 \\
                            1 - e^{-2} & \text{ for } 0 \leq x < 6 \\ 
                            1 - e^{-\frac{v}{3}} & \text{ for } x \geq 6
          \end{cases} $$
My task is to find the decomposition $Q$, consisting of discrete and absolutely continuous parts,  of this CDF. My current solution to this problem is
$$ Q = (1-e^{-2})\delta_0 + (e^{-2})\text{Exp} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) $$
but I am not confident in this solution, namely because this $Q$ implies that there is an exponential distribution beginning at $x = 0$. I was thinking of appending another $\delta_6$ on the exponential term to designate that it begins at $x = 6$, but I do not think that matches the CDF.

My question really boils down to the following: how do I designate that I am only taking the exponential distribution for $x \geq 6$ when I am writing a decomposition of this CDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDF of random variable $V$ was found to be
$$ F_V(v) = \begin{cases}
                        0 & \text{ for } v < 0 \\
                        1 - e^{-2} & \text{ for } 0 \leq v < 6 \\ 
                        1 - e^{-\frac{v}{3}} & \text{ for } v \geq 6 \\
        \end{cases} $$
We may write this CDF as a composition of discrete and absolutely continuous components, which is to say
$$F_V(v) = \sum_{j=1}^{k} p_j F_j(v)$$
where each $F_j(v)$ is either a discrete or absolutely continuous CDF, $p_j$ is a scalar associated with each $F_j(v)$ such that the sum of these coefficients equals $1
        $, and $k$ is the total number of distinct functions that compose $F_V(v)$. Hence, we may write
$$F_V(v) = (1-e^{-2}) F_1(v) + (e^{-2}) F_2(v)$$
where
$$ F_1(v) = \begin{cases}  
            0 & \text{ for } v < 0 \\
            1 & \text{ for } v \geq 0
        \end{cases}$$
and
$$
        F_2(v) = \begin{cases}
            0 & \text{ for } v < 6\\
            1-e^{\frac{6-x}{3}} & \text{ for } v \geq 6
        \end{cases}
        $$
Note that $F_1(v)$ is a valid CDF corresponding to some discrete random variable and $F_2(v)$ is a valid CDF corresponding to some absolutely continuous random variable.

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be

$ X \sim \text{Exp(1/3)}$ (i.e. X is chosen according to an exponential distribution with rate $\frac{1}{3}$)

$ Q = F(X)$ with $F(x) = x 1_{\{x \ge 6\}}$.
In this way for $x \in (0,6)$ it holds $F(x) = P(Q \in [0,x]) = 1-e^{-2} = P(X \le 6)$ and for $x \ge 6$ it holds $F(x) = P(Q \le x) = 1-e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$.

I hope this answers this part:

> My question really boils down to the following: how do I designate that I am only taking the exponential distribution for x≥6 when I am writing a decomposition of this CDF?

Also keep in mind that in your solution you have $P(Q< 1-e^{-2}) = 0$ because you have a deterministic summand in the dirac delta. I think the more appropriate way to denote your idea would be

$Y\sim Ber(1-e^{-2}) $ with $Ber$ being the Bernoulli distribution and

$Q = Y \delta_0 + (1-Y) Z$, where $Z = e^{-2} \text{exp}(\frac{1}{3})$, i.e. with probability $1-e^{-2}$ you have zero and else you use some exponential distribution. (However this solution would still not be correct because you dont account for the fact that the exponential part has to be at least 6).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this helps out a ton!